# Is it possible to use batch scripts in a GUI made with Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, batch-file

I was wondering if it was possible to write a GUI in python, and then somewhere in the python script, insert a script switch to temporarily change the language to accomodate for the batch snippet.

I know this can be done in html and vbscript but what about Python?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "script switch"? "batch snippet"? et cetera.

Comment: @Chris he seems to be thinking of the way that you can embed Javascript in an HTML document, and wants to know if there's anything analogous for embedding windows batch script in Python.

Comment: sure, it's *possible*, but if you can write it all in Python it's much better. Mixing languages is not generally desirable - it makes for more effort required to understand a snippet.

Comment: well the reason i am doing this is that i like the simplicity of pythons gui's, however i am much better at using batch for programming, so i wanted to build a gui in python, and then (quoted from david4dev's post) use a subprocess module in python to insert a batch snippet. so what i need is examples

Answer (score 3):

You can control other processes, written with any language, including bash using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is the most powerful and complete method for executing other processes. However, there's also a very simple method using the [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) module: `os.system(command)` runs `command` just as if you were to type it into a command line.

Comment: ok this is great! is there a way to run a full batch file instead of just one command? like maybe a call function?